# Matlab equivalent in Python: logical XOR on arrays of different lengths?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, xor

I want to convert Matlab code which is doing an XOR on two vectors into Python. I have tried to do this using the numpy.logical_xor() function but this is failing because the two arrays being compared are not of the same shape, preventing broadcasting from working.

The Matlab code I'm trying to emulate:

```
test5=setxor(1:length(test2(test3)),test4);
```

The current (non-working) attempt at the above in Python:

```
test5 = np.logical_xor(np.array(range(len(test2[test3]))), test4)
```

When this line executes I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (366217,) (120655,)
```

I also get the same result when I add an axis to each of the arrays using numpy.expand_dims(), I get messages such as

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1, 366217) (1, 120655)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (366217,1) (120655,1)
```

The issue is the different lengths of test2[test3] and test4, and it seems that the Matlab setxor() functino works fine on vectors of different lengths but the numpy equivalent requires vectors of equal length.

How can I perform an XOR on two 1-D numpy arrays of different lengths? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding what is happening in the Matlab code and/or using the wrong Python function for this?

Comment: It might be easier to help if you gave a simple example of desired input and output (with test2, test3, and test4 of much smaller sizes), and explain in words what the Matlab code is meant to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB/Octave `setxor`

> Return the elements exclusive to A or B, sorted in ascending order.

that's a set operation

```
octave:2> setxor([1,2,3,4],[5,3])
ans =
   1   2   4   5
```

`np.logical_xor` is an element by element comparison, not a `set` operation.

I think there are some `set` operations in `numpy`, but I'd have look them up.  I know there is a `set` class in Python

```
In [176]: x=set([1,2,3,4])    
In [177]: x.symmetric_difference([5,3])
Out[177]: set([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

`setdiff1d` is a `set difference` function, which could be used as

```
In [188]: xa=np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [189]: ya=np.array([5,3])
In [190]: np.concatenate([np.setdiff1d(xa,ya),np.setdiff1d(ya,xa)])
Out[190]: array([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

It uses `np.unique` and `np.in1d`; a setxor could be rewritten using those functions.

```
In [199]: np.concatenate([xa[np.in1d(xa,ya,invert=True)],
      ya[np.in1d(ya,xa,invert=True)]])
Out[199]: array([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

(may want to use `xa=np.unique(xa)` etc first).

My guess is that if there is a defined `setxor` function it will be built from these same pieces.

---

Bingo, a Google search on `numpy set operations` produced:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html

```
In [201]: np.setxor1d(xa,ya)
Out[201]: array([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

It does: (for 2 unique arrays)

```
    aux = np.concatenate( (ar1, ar2) )
    aux.sort()
    flag = np.concatenate( ([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1], [True] ) )
    flag2 = flag[1:] == flag[:-1]
    return aux[flag2]
```

So it makes a sorted concatenation of the arrays, and then removes the elements that aren't unique.

Comment: Excellent answer, this is exactly the solution, it works for me now. Thanks!